# Cannot login on Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

Our hosting provider upgraded Artifactory to Artifactory Pro 4.12.1 today.
I was able to enter the license key and I can see that all Pro features are available.

When I press the Login link in the top right corner, I get https://REPOSERVER/webapp/#/login

I enter the admin username+password and click login.

The URL briefly flashes to https://REPOSERVER/webapp/#/home and then back to https://REPOSERVER/webapp/#/login, so I cannot login.

In `/usr/local/artifactory/logs/access.log` I can find several lines with `[ACCEPTED LOGIN]  for admin/IPADDRESS.`

Comment: Our hosting provider solved it. They didn't tell me how. Vote to close my own question because not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Try a hard refresh on the page in your browser.

When you upgrade Artifactory from major versions, your browser's cache will have kept some configurations from your old installation. These can cause the above glitches. This may happen no matter what browser you are using.

You can confirm it's only your browser's cache by going directly to a repository. Try going to http://$art_url:$art_port/artifactory/$repo_name and see if you can browse the artifacts there.

Comment: Lifesaver answer @Patrick Russell, thank you. Clearing cookies solved the problem.