# Artifactory cannot login with local accounts

Tags: artifactory

I've setup an artifactory server. No problems. I've bound the system to Active Directory, and my AD users can login with no problems.  However, we setup a new local account (non-AD account), and that local account can't login.  It sits and spins at the login screen when I put in the credentials, but it always dumps me out to the anonymous home screen.  I tried to login with the "admin" user, and it now also does the same thing.  I check the log files, and I'm getting **[ACCEPTED LOGIN]** for the user in question in the access.log file, just like my AD users.  So it is authenticating me correctly, but it seems to log me out right away and I go back to an anonymous user on the home screen.

This is the same behavior as this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394719/cannot-login-on-artifactory).  However, clearing my browser's cache doesn't change the behavior, which seems to have solved it for some people.

EDIT:
I am using Apache as a reverse proxy in front of it for HTTPS.  However, as part of my troubleshooting I opened up port 8081 to do a direct connection.  When hitting port 8081 directly over HTTP, same results. As part of troubleshooting, I also upgraded to version 6.7.0.f

EDIT:
Here are the additional logs requested.  There are different numbers of lines between the two logins, but nothing obvious.

```
<artifactoryHome>/access/logs/request.log

Successful Login with AD account bjackson:
2019-02-06T20:42:58.955+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|POST|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/auth/authenticate|200|38|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:43:44.242+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/bjackson|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:43:44.245+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/bjackson|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:43:44.247+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/bjackson|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:43:44.249+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/bjackson|200|0|1|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:43:44.256+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|PUT|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/last_login/bjackson|204|65|6|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:43:44.257+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/permissions/last_updated|200|0|1|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:43:44.260+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/bjackson|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:43:44.280+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/admin|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41

Logoff with AD account bjackson:
2019-02-06T20:44:20.146+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|POST|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/auth/authenticate|200|38|3|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:44:20.149+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/permissions/last_updated|200|0|1|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:44:20.151+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/anonymous|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41


Not working with local account testing:
2019-02-06T20:46:05.672+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/testing|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:46:05.702+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|POST|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/auth/authenticate|200|48|29|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:46:05.705+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/testing|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:46:05.707+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/testing|200|0|2|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:46:05.714+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|PUT|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/last_login/testing|204|65|7|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:46:05.715+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/permissions/last_updated|200|0|1|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41
2019-02-06T20:46:05.717+0000|127.0.0.1|jfrt@01csmgp7kfwanf0g94sghc0e47|GET|http://localhost:8040/access/api/v1/users/testing|200|0|1|JFrog Access Java Client/4.1.41

<artifactoryHome>/logs/access.log
2019-02-06 20:43:44,247 [ACCEPTED LOGIN]  for bjackson/172.16.0.10.
2019-02-06 20:46:05,705 [ACCEPTED LOGIN]  for testing/172.16.0.10.
```

Comment: Are you accessing Artifactory directly or do you have an http proxy, firewall, corporate proxy in front of Artifactory?
Which version of Artifactory are you using?

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky Thank you for your comments.  I updated the posting to include those details.  Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: there will be some audit logs which should provide more info. path is <artifactory_home>/access/logs/audit.log

Comment: @yashbagarka Thank you for your comment. I updated the original post with the log details you requested.  The audit log hasn't been updated in a while and only contains one line.  Only the access.log file contained any updated information when I tried to login with my local account in the <arifactory_home>/access/logs folder.  Do I need to increase the log level?